# rrdtool y-axis values "200m" instead of "0.2"

Tags: graph, rrdtool, rrd

I've got a rrd which contains mostly values 0 to 1 (linux load avarage).

Sometimes the graph displays at the y-axis => "0.1 0.2 ... 0.9". That's the way I want it.

But other times, I see the following "100m 200m ...".

Is there a way to force displaying as "0.1 etc." values?

Answer (score 17):

`-X 0` did the trick.

[-X|--units-exponent value]

This sets the 10**exponent scaling of the y-axis values. Normally, values will be scaled to the appropriate units (k, M, etc.). However, you may wish to display units always in k (Kilo, 10e3) even if the data is in the M (Mega, 10e6) range, for instance. Value should be an integer which is a multiple of 3 between -18 and 18 inclusively. It is the exponent on the units you wish to use. For example, use 3 to display the y-axis values in k (Kilo, 10e3, thousands), use -6 to display the y-axis values in u (Micro, 10e-6, millionths). Use a value of 0 to prevent any scaling of the y-axis values.